# ngModel directive not working with selected option

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a quite simple form on my ionic 2 app. The code is as bellow:

```
      <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onBuscar(f)">
          <ion-item>

              <ion-label>Ano/Mês</ion-label>

              <ion-select
                  name="ano"
                  ngModel
                  required
                  okText="Confirmar"
                  cancelText="Cancelar"
                >
                <ion-option *ngFor="let ano of anos" value="{{ano}}" selected="{{ano==ano_atual}}">
                    {{ano}}
                </ion-option>
              </ion-select>

              <ion-select
                name="mes"
                ngModel
                required
                okText="Confirmar"
                cancelText="Cancelar"
              >
                <ion-option *ngFor="let mes of meses; let i = index" value="{{i + 1}}" selected="{{i==mes_atual}}">
                    {{mes}}
                </ion-option>
              </ion-select>

            </ion-item>

      </form>
```

The problem is: my default selected option is having some problem when I put that "ngModel" directive. Without it, it works fine. However, I need it to get my form values on my component when the form is submitted. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how ngModel should be used. Assuming `ano_atual` is the property from the component where you want to save the selected value, you can do this:

```
<ion-select name="ano" [(ngModel)]="ano_atual" required okText="Confirmar" cancelText="Cancelar">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let ano of anos" value="{{ano}}">
    {{ano}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Please notice that you don't need the `selected` attribute, since the option with the same value as the `ano_atual` property will be selected because of the *ngModel* directive.

Comment: Thanks, I did it like that and it worked. But what if I don't wanna bind it to a property from my component, but still wanna the selected property and wanna pass the values to my component function?